# How can I select an HTML tag's content in Vim?

Tags: vim, selection

Is it possible to select an HTML tag's content in Vim?

For example:

```
<p>I am a silly butterfly</p>
```

I would like to select "I am a silly butterfly".

I know that you can use `vi"` to select text inside quotes, brackets, etc. The problem here is that the text inside the HTML tags is not really within anything that I can use the `i` function for.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use `vit` to `v`isually select text `i`n a `t`ag. See

```
:help v_it
```

Comment: Perfect! Gonna write a post about this in my blog, I couldn't find anything on Google with "Vim selecting html tag contents" and others.

Comment: You can also substitute `v` with many other commands, I often use `c` to `c`hange; `>` and `<` to fix indentation.

Comment: How do you select the tags as well? In this case the `<p>` tags.

Comment: @hobbes3: To include the tags in the selection, use `vat`. I think of `it` as *in* a tag and `at` as *a* tag. See `:help at`.

Comment: Am I the only one whose vim selects the opening tag with `vit`? It's been bothering me for years and have no idea why Vim does that.

Comment: Note that you can also use both multiple times, eg. `vatat`

Answer (score 13):

Here are the steps:

1. Place the cursor on the tag.
2. Enter Visual mode by pressing <kbd>v</kbd>.
3. Select the inner tag block by pressing <kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> (or <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for outer tag block).

> <kbd>at</kbd>      a `<tag> </tag>` block (with tags)
>
> <kbd>it</kbd>      inner `<tag> </tag>` block

See more at "[How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467)".

Answer (score 1):

If the format is well indent like this,

```
<div>
  <p>
    I am a silly butterfly
  </p>
  <p>
    I am a silly butterfly
  </p>
</div>
```

You use can [vim-indent-object](https://github.com/michaeljsmith/vim-indent-object) plugin, and type <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>