# How to navigate between begin and end html tag in Vim?

Tags: vim, html, gvim

For example, if I want to jump to the close `form` tag. how could I do this?

Comment: Related: [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The matchit.vim plugin, in conjunction with the html.vim filetype plugin, will allow you to do this.  One way to load the matchit.vim plugin is to put this in your ~/.vimrc:

```
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

If you don't already have filetype plugins enabled, also put this in in your ~/.vimrc:

```
filetype plugin on
```

Then when you edit an HTML file, you can jump from a tag to the matching tag by typing `%`. You can find out more by executing

```
:help matchit
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! Thought I had to install plugin but looks like it's included already.

Comment: Seems like this is possible without installing a plugin, at least in neovim.

Answer (score 18):

You can jump between tags using visual operators, in example:

1. Place the cursor on the tag.
2. Enter visual mode by pressing <kbd>v</kbd>.
3. Select the outer tag block by pressing <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for inner tag block.

Your cursor should jump forward to the matching closing html/xml tag. To jump backwards from closing tag, press <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> to jump to opposite tag.

Now you can either exit visual by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, change it by <kbd>c</kbd> or copy by <kbd>y</kbd>.

---

To record that action into register, press <kbd>qq</kbd> to start recording, perform tag jump as above (including <kbd>Esc</kbd>), press <kbd>q</kbd> to finish. Then to invoke jump, press <kbd>@q</kbd>.

---

See more help at `:help visual-operators` or `:help v_it`:

> <kbd>at</kbd>      a `<tag> </tag>` block (with tags)
>
> <kbd>it</kbd>      inner `<tag> </tag>` block

---

Alternatively use plugin such as [matchit.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) (See: [Using % in languages without curly braces](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/using-in-languages-without-curly-braces)).

---

See also:

- [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467) at Vim SE
- [Jump to matching XML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500989/jump-to-matching-xml-tags-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [How can I find the close html tag quickly in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116362/how-can-i-find-the-close-html-tag-quickly-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [Navigating HTML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270396/navigating-html-tags-in-vim) at stackoverflow SE
- [VIM jump from one xml tag to the closing one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38187/vim-jump-from-one-xml-tag-to-the-closing-one) at Unix SE
- [How can I select an html tag's content in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/182355/how-can-i-select-an-html-tags-content-in-vim) at superuser SE